# How to Make Adobe Air as a Java Library

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, flash, air-native-extension

I have an Adobe Air project for Android written in ActionScript on Flash Builder. I was wondering if I can somehow make this Air project to a java library so that another of my Android project written in Java on eclipse can use it?

I have been looking into the Adobe Air native extension with Java. But it seems what the native extension doing is to run native Java code in Adobe Air. I want to do the opposite.

1. I look into JNI but it can be used to call c/c++/assembly, didn't see the approach to call actionscript.
2. Just found out there may be a way to call Air stand alone project from Java through java.lang.Runtime. But it may take 1-10 sec to open the stand alone Air project. Is there anyway I can integrate Air application into Java?
3. If I have to call the stand alone project from Java, then the next problem came, my Air stand alone project will play rtmp live stream. However, that needs to have Flash Player which Android/iOS device do not support it. Is there any way to play rtmp rather than using VLC player? I heard VLC player have 1-2 second delay.

Updates:
So someone told me to look into Haxe. It can compile AS3 to jar and Java can use it. http://www.haxe.org
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1541206